# Increase maximum zoom level on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an image overlay on a mkmapview.

I can't seem to zoom in the image once i reach the max zoom in values of the map.
I still have a lot of zooming in to the image to do.

Any ideas?
Like how can i change the max zoom in value of the map?