# increase MKMapView maximum zoom level

Tags: cocoa, mapkit

unanswered possible dupe: [Increase maximum zoom level on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236576/increase-maximum-zoom-level-on-mkmapview)

I have a `MKMapView` with a custom subclassed `MKTileOverlay`. The overlay's `canReplaceMapContent` is set to `YES`. And even though the overlay's `maximumZ` property is set high (21), I can only get zoomed in to about 19. I've tried this alternately through setting the region and setting the map camera's altitude.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1) say:

"The map view can’t display arbitrary zoom levels and must adjust any regions you specify to match the zoom levels it supports."

However, I've told it to support up to level 21, and my custom tiles go that high. I know the framework can support it, because the OSX Maps app can get very close with satellite view.

What gives?

Comment: Same problem here... did you come to a solution since June?

Comment: update: no solution to this particular problem. I ended up using a hierarchy of layer-hosting views with a CATiledLayer which gets tiles from MapBox static tiles API, and CG* for drawing above the map.